# How can I take out data of lists?

Tags: python, list, range

I want to calculate the difference between the second last number (`x[1]`) and the other numbers of the different items in the list (`list`).

In the first item of the list, it should be 19-13 (= 6), 19-16 and 19-19. The problem is that the items in the list consist of 3 or 4 (sometimes 5/6) numbers.

```
list = [([(13, 400), (14, 700), (19, 700)], 19, 1800),
              ([(24, 250), (28, 650), (35, 100), (43, 600)], 43, 1600),
              ([(46, 450), (48, 600), (78, 450)], 78, 1500),
              ([(79, 650), (88, 400), (92, 600), (96, 50)], 98, 1700)]

1= []
for x in list:
    1.append(x[0][0][0])
print "1", 1

2= []
for xin list:
    2.append(x[0][1][0])
print "2", 2

3= []
for xin list:
    3.append(x[0][2][0])
print "3", 3

4= []
for xin list:
    4.append(x[0][3][0])
print "4", 4

time= []
for xin list:
    time.append(x[1])
print time
```

Result:

```
1 [13, 24, 46, 79]
2 [14, 28, 48, 88]
3 [19, 35, 78, 92]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    4.append(order[0][3][0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error only appears if the list consist of items which consist of less than 4 items. Because then the `[3]` in `[0][3][0]` will find an "empty item".

---

Thank you nigel222, both worked but I used your first suggestion. To create two lists of the same length i used the else: function:

```
for x in list:
    if len(x[0]) >= 4:
        4.append(x[0][3][0])
    else:
        fourthorder.append(order[1])
```

Afterwards I calculate the difference between x[1] and the 4 lists, so if else: is used, x[1]-x[1] gives 0.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where these differences are calculated and stored, nor what do you want in them depending on how many, 3–6, of the corresponding items there were in `servedbook`. Please [edit] your question and add this code and information.

Comment: You can't have variables named `1`, `2`, etc. Variable names must start with an alphabetic character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main ways to go: test in advance, or handle the exception, always assuming you know exactly what to do when there is no fourth item.

Check first:

```
fourthorder_arrival_of_batch = []
for order in servedbook:
    if len( order[0]) > 3:
        fourthorder_arrival_of_batch.append(order[0][3][0])
    #else:
        #append a default value if desired
print "4", fourthorder_arrival_of_batch
```

handle exception

```
fourthorder_arrival_of_batch = []
for order in servedbook:
    try:
        fourthorder_arrival_of_batch.append(order[0][3][0])
    except IndexError:
        #append a default value if desired, or
        pass
print "4", fourthorder_arrival_of_batch
```

Exceptions should be the unusual case, because a handled exception is more expensive than a simple test done in advance. But if less than (say) ten percent are exceptional, then this will rarely if ever matter and if the test is not simple, then handling the exceptions may be more efficient.

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds, was just formatting response! It's worth noting on your last point though that the python documentation states: `Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.` I guess you have to be sensible too, though :)

Comment: @roganjosh In most cases handling an exception is either insignificantly slower or, when the test is itself expensive, faster. The exceptions are where the test is simple (as here) *and* the exceptional case is actually the common. Even then, it only matters if this part of the code is an inner loop contributing significantly to a significant CPU-usage. (It's also confusing to read if the "exception" is vastly more likely than the "normal" code path, unless commented).